# How to Edit Textmate shortcuts

Tags: textmate, edit, restore, shortcut

I don't know how I did it, 
but I lost the ⌘/ commenting shortcut.
I normally use it a lot.

I've checked if a different app in osx 10.6.6
"System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts"
it as a hot key but it appears to be still available.

Does anyone know how to get it back?

Comment: Done! Thank you, I should'v thought of that before

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Source bundle's definition. Choose Bundles>Bundle Editor>Show Bundle Editor, find the Source bundle, click the disclosure triangle for it and find the Comment Line / Selection command. Make sure the Activation is set to Key Equivalent and that the equivalent is ⌘/.

Comment: " Make sure the Activation is set to Key Equivalent and that the equivalent is ⌘/."  

Please excuse my ignorance but, How to do that?

The 'Activation:' is set to 'Key Equivalent' but 
it has grey'd out & can't be clicked on to be selected

Comment: Odd. Does anything happen when you press ⌘/? It sounds like the problem is deeper than TextMate, perhaps something at the OS level. I know you said you checked the Keyboard System Pref, but perhaps you can double-check it. If nothing else turns up, since you can't seem to change the key equivalent on the existing command would be to create a new command, copying the existing command's script and assign that to something similar, such as Opt-Cmd-/. Doesn't solve the underlying problem, but would give you key access to the command.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was 1Password.

I'd changed the default shortcut for Go & Fill to ⌘/.
Changing 1Password's shortcut and restarting the 1PasswordAgent (from within Activity Monitor) fixed the problem for me.